# Laravel 4 model relationship through another model

Tags: php, model, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to bind multiple models to a form.  Currently, I have 4 models:

```
<?php

class DemDataSet extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $connection = 'epcr_dem_data';
    protected $table = 'DEMDataSet';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pk_DEMDataSet';

    public function DemographicReport(){
        return $this->hasOne('DemographicReport','fk_DemDataSet','pk_DemDataSet');
    }

}

class DemographicReport extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $connection = 'epcr_dem_data';
    protected $table = 'DemographicReport';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pk_DemographicReport';

    public function DemDataSet(){
        return $this->belongsTo('DemDataSet','fk_DemDataSet','pk_DemDataSet');
    }

    public function dAgency(){
        return $this->hasOne('dAgency','fk_DemographicReport','pk_DemographicReport');
    }

}

class dAgency extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $connection = 'epcr_dem_data';
    protected $table = 'dAgency';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pk_dAgency';

    public function DemographicReport(){
        return $this->belongsTo('DemographicReport','fk_DemographicReport','pk_DemographicReport');
    }

    public function dAgency_10(){
        return $this->hasMany('dAgency_10','fk_dAgency','pk_dAgency');
    }

}

class dAgency_10 extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $connection = 'epcr_dem_data';
    protected $table = 'dAgency_10';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pk_dAgency_10';

    public function dAgency(){
        return $this->belongsTo('dAgency','fk_dAgency','pk_dAgency');
    }

}

?>
```

And I'm passing it to my view through my controller like so:

```
public function index()
{
    //THIS is the line I need help with (I think):
    $agency = dAgency::with('dAgency_10','DemographicReport')->find(1);

    //for troubleshooting:
    echo "<pre>",print_r(dAgency::with('dAgency_10','DemographicReport')->find(1)->toArray()),"</pre>";

    return View::make('test')
        ->with('agency', $agency);
}
```

I'm able to bind everything except for data from the DemDataSet model, which I can't even figure out how to establish the relationship between it and my dAgency model.  So basically, I just want the fields in the DemDataSet model to be available to my view, then obviously I want to be able to perform all the CRUD operations eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your models, you should just be able to access it via the `DemographicReport`.

i.e.,

```
$dataset = $agency->DemographicReport->DemDataSet;
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.  When I call `echo "<pre>",print_r($agency->DemographicReport),"</pre>";` in my controller, I get `[relations:protected] => Array ([DemDataSet] => )` indicating that the DemDataSet is empty.  But when I look in the results from that model (`echo "<pre>",print_r(DemDataSet::find(1)),"</pre>";`), it clearly has data.  I double checked my hasOne() and belongsTo() any they seem correct.

Comment: Does `$agency->DemographicReport` have a value for `fk_DemDataSet`?

Comment: Yes, it does.  There is clearly a problem with my models' relations.  I have a similar question that is likely the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165781/laravel-4-deleting-multiple-models-related-by-foreign-keys .  I made it before I really thought about the possibility of this one being the same problem.  Thanks for taking a look man, I've been beating myself up over this and I know it's probably something really simple.