# Laravel 4 deleting multiple models related by foreign keys

Tags: php, model, laravel-4, foreign-keys

So I have three models and when when one of them `dAgency` is deleted `delete-()` I'd like all three to be deleted.  The problem is that two of them are being deleted, while the top parent one `DemDataSet` isn't being deleted.  Additionally, when I call:

`echo "<pre>", dd(dAgency::find(21)->DemographicReport()->DemDataSet()->get()), "</pre>";`

I get this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::DemDataSet()`  But when I try:

`echo "<pre>", dd(dAgency::find(21)->DemographicReport()->get()), "</pre>";`

It works.  So I know the problem is my relation between my DemDataSet model.  Below is my model:

```
<?php

class DemDataSet extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $connection = 'epcr_dem_data';
    protected $table = 'DEMDataSet';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pk_DEMDataSet';

    public function DemographicReport(){
        return $this->hasOne('DemographicReport','fk_DEMDataSet','pk_DEMDataSet');
    }


}

class DemographicReport extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $connection = 'epcr_dem_data';
    protected $table = 'DemographicReport';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pk_DemographicReport';

    public function DemDataSet (){
        return $this->belongsTo('DemDataSet','fk_DEMDataSet','pk_DEMDataSet');
    }

    public function dAgency(){
        return $this->hasOne('dAgency','fk_DemographicReport','pk_DemographicReport');
    }

    public function delete(){
        parent::delete();
        return $this->DemDataSet()->delete();
    }

}

class dAgency extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $connection = 'epcr_dem_data';
    protected $table = 'dAgency';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pk_dAgency';

    public function DemographicReport(){
        return $this->belongsTo('DemographicReport','fk_DemographicReport','pk_DemographicReport');
    }

    public function dAgency_10(){
        return $this->hasMany('dAgency_10','fk_dAgency','pk_dAgency');
    }

    public function delete(){
        parent::delete();
        return $this->DemographicReport->delete();
    }

}

?>
```

I've been wrestling with this one for two days now!  I really appreciate you taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to query laravel model with relationship is this way:

```
//This is to pull all DemDataSet from DemographicReport
dAgency::find(21)->DemographicReport()->first()->DemDataSet;

//If you need further query, then you call DemDataSet as a method
dAgency::find(21)->DemographicReport()->first()->DemDataSet()->where('your condition here')->get();
```

Comment: Didn't work.  When I try the first line, I get this error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$DemDataSet`  But this works: `DemographicReport::find(18)->DemDataSet->get()` So I'm unable to make a relation for dAgency to DemDataSet.  I get an undefined method error on the second line of code you provided.

Comment: Alright edited the solution though it might not be what your desired, so basically that will returns the DemDataSet from the first DemographicReport that belongs to dAgency with id=21

Comment: Your new update fixed the error, but it causes an extra query (one for each of the two joined tables). I should have been more specific in my question, but how would I do this using eager? I can do `dAgency::with('DemographicReport')->find($id)`, but when I try putting DEMDataSet in `with()` it throws the same error as before. I'm guessing it's because I don't have a DemDataSet() method in my dAgency class, but since there isn't a direct relationship between those tables (they are related through the other one), how would I do that?

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible to change the structure of your table slightly, assuming that DemDataSet only belongs to 1 DemographicReport and the DomographicReport only belongs to 1 dAgency, it'll make the query easier if you just add FK to DemoDataSet tables with dAgency_id, with that you have a direct relationship between the 2.

Comment: Nope, I can't really change the structure, but the good news is that it's working!  I guess I was just having issues wrapping my head around the model classes themselves.  You're last update sent me down the right path so I'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks for the help - not a lot of good places to get L4 help, SO doesn't seem to have a big L$ community.